# How to interpret or calculate this sum?

Tags: summation, multiplicative-order

I am trying to solve the following mathematical equation:

$4[8\sum q_1(1 - q_1).q_2(1-q_2)]$

$q_1$ = is a vector of length $10000$, with values between $0-1$ $q_2$ = is a vector of length $10000$, with values between $0-1$

My question is how the order of the calculations should be, I have two exclusive possibilities in mind:

1) solve first $q_1(1 - q_1)$ times $q_2(1-q_2)$, and then make the summation of this values, and finally multiply by $8$ and $4$.

2) make first separately the summation of $q_1(1 - q_1)$ and the summation of $q_2(1 - q_2)$, and then multiply each other, and finally multiply by 8 and by 4

The results are different so I am not sure which is the correct one.

Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you mean $q_1(1-q+1)$ in the sum or $q_1(1-q_1)$? It's confusing from the question vs. equation.

Comment: Sorry it was a problem with the spelling, I have corrected now. It is $q_1(1−q_1)$.

Comment: If you want $\sum(ab)$, why would you calculate $(\sum a)(\sum b)$?

Comment: I work mostly on biology and I am not sure how the ∑ affect the rest of the operation that come after. If I understood correctly your comment I could think that the right way to solve this is the number 1 that i gave in my example. Do you think this?

Comment: I think $\sum f$ means add up a bunch of values of $f$. If $f$ happens to take the form of a product $gh$, then $\sum f$ means add up a bunch of values of $gh$. Do you add up values of $gh$ by adding up values of $g$, adding up values of $h$, and then multiplying? Do you work out $(2\times3)+(4\times5)$ by working out $2+4$ and $3+5$ and then multiplying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to solve the following mathematical equation:
>
> $4[8\sum q_1(1 - q_1).q_2(1-q_2)]$

In order to compute this, you need the values over which to sum these terms.  So let's write $q_{1,k}$ for the $k$-th entry of $q_1$ ans similar for $q_2$.  Presumably, the sum extends over all of the 10000 elements, and depending on programming language, the array index extends run from 0 to 9999 or from 1 to 10000.  Let's assume C convention (0 to 9999), then your term denotes as:

$$
4\Big(8\sum_{k=0}^{9999} q_{1,k}·(1 - q_{1,k})\cdot q_{2,k}·(1-q_{2,k})\Big)
$$
which is
$$32\Big(
q_{1,0}·(1 - q_{1,0})\cdot q_{2,0}·(1-q_{2,0})
+\cdots+
q_{1,9999}·(1 - q_{1,9999})\cdot q_{2,9999}·(1-q_{2,9999})
\Big)
$$
Denoted in some pseudo language:

```
sum ← 0
for k from 0 to 9999
    sum ← sum + q1[k] * (1 - q1[k]) * q2[k] * (1 - q2[k])
result ← 4 * 8 * sum
```

There are also languages like [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) that can efficiently and conveniently handle vectors and such (and are wide spread in biology), hence with such a language you don't want to operate entry-by-entry by hand.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I am going to try to solve this with R.